# Java regular expression not working for MULTILINE entries

Tags: java, regex

this is my Java code:

```
String patternParticipants = "([\\w\\.=-]+@[\\w\\.-]+\\.[\\w]{2,3}($|\n))*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternParticipants, Pattern.MULTILINE); 
boolean matchesParticipants = p.matcher(reservation.getParticipants().trim()).matches();
```

And I want to match the following string:

```
john.wales@gmail.com
david.chrome@gmail.com
david.mika@gui.co
```

For some reason, matcher returns `true` only if one email address is given. 
I've tried to set it for MULTILINE but this seems not to be working too. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out tools like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Show your code. Explain what specifically is not working.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I forgot to mention, it is OK in all regular expression tools I have tried online.... Java automatically adds double slashes (instead of single), I thought maybe that could be an issue?

Comment: You should read up on what a String literal is.

Comment: @tnw it is just one small check in a massive validator class... with method matches (like many other things that are checked in the same way), I am validation this kind of input. Funny, but it works when it's only one line

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis sure, but isn't it funny when it recognizes one email address, but not multiline? so I guess it's exactly about RE

Comment: You have to set it up for multiline. Again, without your code, we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

Strip the new line character first, and then run your RegEx on it.

Use a code like this to strip the '\n'.

```
String text = readFileAsString("textfile.txt");
text.replace("\n", "");
```

P.S: Your data to be in textfile.txt.

Later, use this RegEx.

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks for a newline (`\n`) or the end of the string (`$`) after each address:

```
static boolean isValidEmailList(String str)
{
  return str.matches("([\\w\\.=-]+@[\\w\\.-]+\\.[\\w]{2,3}($|\n))+");
}
```

Your regular expression will erroneously invalidate many valid email addresses, and allow some invalid addresses. But this is one way to make it work on your multi-line input.

Answer (score -1):

^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*
      @[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$;

You should use this one for Email